# Is $(\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+, *) \simeq (A, \cdot)$ where $A$ is the set of all numbers that are the product of 2 and 3

Tags: abstract-algebra

EDIT: Binary Structures not groups

Is $(\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+, *) \simeq (A, \cdot)$ where $A$ is the set of all numbers the are the product of 2 and 3 and $*$ is defined as $(a,b) * (c,d) = (a+c, b+d)$  The products must contains at least one 2 and one 3 in order to be in $A$

Seems like $A$ is equivalent to $6\mathbb{Z}^{nonzero}$

I think it isn't isomorphic because I'm not finding a one-to-one map but I could be wrong. Neither have an identity element and both are commutative so they seem to share structural properties.

If I make $\phi: \mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+ \to A$  defined by $\phi(x,y)=6xy, x=a+c \,\text{and}\, y = b+d$ then its definitely not one-to-one.

maybe there is a one-to-one mapping i am missing though.

Comment: what do you mean by isomorphism here??? they have no group structure...

Comment: they are binary structures, not  groups

Comment: $(x,y)\to 2^x 3^y$ is what you want.

Comment: can you tell me the definiton of isomorphism here?

Comment: the will be isomorphic if the mapping is one-to-one, onto and has the homomorphism property

Answer (score 1):

The map $(n,m) \mapsto 2^n 3^m$ from $(\mathbb{N}^2,+)$ to $(\mathbb{N}^{\ast}, \times)$ is an injective homomorphism of semigroups with identity.

From  $(\mathbb{Z}^2,+)$ to $(\mathbb{Q}^{\ast}, \times)$ it is an injective homomorphism of groups.

Now, restrict the co-domain to the image (and chose the one you want in your context that is not completely clear).

Comment: $\phi((1,2) * (1,2)) = 2^23^4 = \phi((1,1)*(1,3))$ that doesn't violate one-to-one?

Comment: I guess it doesn't cause (2,4) is an element of the structure not necessarily concerned with how that element came about in terms of one-to-one.

Comment: Your second comment is correct.